# .TotalSeconds in C# XNA

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xna

Following my recent Asked Question (which was answered; thanks very much for the help!) I have progressed a little further but hit another brick wall. I'm fairly new to C#, and can't seem to get past an error message I'm recieving:  "'NullReferenceException was unhandled' Object reference not set to an instance of an object". I am attempting to create some sort of timer that counts up slowly from 1 to 50, every 2 seconds. The code I am using is below. If what I've provided isn't sufficient, let me know and I will edit.

```
namespace RealTimeStrategyGame
{
    class ResourceCounter
    {
    Vector2 position;
    Texture2D sprite;
    Rectangle boundingbox;
    bool over, clicked;
    SpriteFont font;
    GameTime gameTime;
    int pSourceCount = 1;
    int limit = 50;
    float countDuration = 2f; //every  2s.
    float currentTime = 0f;



    public ResourceCounter(Vector2 pos, GameTime gameTime)
    {
        position = pos;
        over = false;
        clicked = false;
        gameTime = new GameTime();

        currentTime += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds; //Time passed since last Update() 

        if (currentTime >= countDuration)
        {
            pSourceCount++;
            //any actions to perform
        }
        if (pSourceCount >= limit)
        {
            pSourceCount = 0;//Reset the counter;

        }


    }





}
}
```

Comment: Which line gives you your null reference exception?

Comment: currentTime += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds; I know it must be a simple answer, but I just can't figure it out! EDIT: Ah, could it be that I have not introduced anywhere to read out the TotalSeconds? I have used variables such as position in the Main class, (where I'd like it read out to the screen) but have not given it anything to display?

Comment: Your `gameTime` variable must be null, can you show us the code where it's declared?

Comment: @Sean Above the code I showed in the Question, I have: namespace RealTimeStrategyGame { class ResourceCounter { Vector2 position; Texture2D sprite; Rectangle boundingbox; bool over, clicked; SpriteFont font; GameTime gameTime;

Comment: If you have more/updated code to post, **edit** your question so that we can see it properly formatted and in context.

Comment: Ok so as Moore91 has pointed out, you'll need to pass the GameTime variable from your main Game class into this function in order to get the values from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont pass GameTime gameTime as a param to the function. Therefore you cannot access gameTime because it is not initialised

```
public ResourceCounter(Vector2 pos, GameTime gameTime)
{
    // stuff

     currentTime += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds; //Time passed since last Update()

    // other stuff
}
```

Edit:

If you pass it into the constructor then make a temp variable and use this for instance

```
private GameTime gameTime;
```

then in constructor

```
this.gameTime = gameTime;
```

Then it will be initialised

Comment: I added the extra parameter, "GameTime gameTime", but recieved the Error of "'RealTimeStrategyGame.ResourceCounter' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments".

Comment: You'll need to pass the `gameTime` variable from your main `Game` class into the constructor for `ResourceCounter` when you create it.

Comment: In the code where this function is called you then need to pass a GameTime paramater. So you will have ResourceCounter(pos, gameTime) for instance. Assuming you have this running in a function with a gameTime param in the first place.

Comment: The problem here isn't really a XNA problem, more one that you do not understand the fundamentals of Object Oriented Programming. I suggest doing a search on passing function parameters before continuing on with this, otherwise you will just run into the same issue time and time again.

Comment: Well in my main `Game` class, (named `GameScreen.cs`) I have the new error: "'RealTimeStrategyGame.ResourceCounter' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments". This is the code for that class: `pSourceCount = new ResourceCounter(new Vector2(30,20));` Edit: I believe you are correct. Thanks everyone for the help nonetheless, and I will come back to this post once I feel I am more prepared.

Comment: So modify it to pass the gameTime parameter from the main game class into the constructor: `pSourceCount = new ResourceCounter(new Vector2(30,20), gameTime);`.